# How to elegantly avoid code duplication, when class T and T_ref only differ in the constructors & destructors?

Tags: c++, inheritance, code-duplication, boilerplate

```cpp
class HugeTpool{            // Owner of *_dataPool memory
    int x;
    int y; 
//   ...  etc;      // Data Members (many)
   size_t* _dataPool;        // pointer to huge contiguous data

    T_ref operator[](int i){    // used to emulate vector<T> like behaviour
    /* Implementation  details*/
    return T_ref_Obj;
    }
};

class T{                    // Owner of *_data memory
    int a;
//    ... etc;       //  Data Members   (few)
    size_t* _data;           // pointer to small contiguous data
   
    T operator+(T){}
//      ... etc;     //  Member functions

// Glue code to enable interoperability with class T_ref
    T operator+(T_ref){}
//    ... etc;
};

class T_ref{                // A reference type, to emulate T class interfaces 
    int a;
//    ... etc;        //  Data Members  (Identical to class T)  
    size_t* _data;          // Does not own *_data memory, only references it

    T operator+(T_ref);
//      ... etc;        //  Member functions (Identical to class T)    

// Glue code to enable interoperability with class T
    T operator+(T){}
//    ... etc;
};
```

Here the `vector<T>` like interface is being emulated upon the underlying `HugeTpool` data structure, with the help of `T_ref` class. `T` and `T_ref` only defer in the management of `*_data` memory. The memory pointed to by `T_ref` must not be freed upon the destruction of a `T_ref` obj. The two classes only defer in copy & move constructors, destructors and assignment operators, and the rest of it is the same.

As `T` and `T_ref` are in essence the same, I need `T` and `T_ref` to be interoperable. which is requiring a lot of glue and boilerplate code. Also, as both class have the same interfaces (and member funcitons), there is a lot of code duplication. Is there an elegant to work around this problem? I have considered inheritence, but it does not seem to suit well for this scenario.

This is a simplified version of my problem, in practice, I have many `_ref` classes and they need to be interoperable with each other. The glue code required to accomplish this is quickly getting out of control.

Comment: It sounds like inheritance is exactly what you need?

Comment: You can "inject" different behavior into a single class template by special template arguments (_policies_). However, this would create for both cases a different class (static polymorphism), which will, e.g., hinder their storage in a single container. Would this suit your needs? Another solution is dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: @AlanBirtles  inheritance does not work here, let `class T_base`, `class T : T_base`. `T_base` will be responsible for constructing/destructing/copying/moving the data members, `T` can only augment or remedy the behaviour, and it is not always possible to get the desired behaviour by remedying the `T_base` behaviour. Also its being wasteful in performance.

Comment: non-polymorphic inheritance shouldn't have any performance penalty. Even polymorphism probably has less impact than you expect. A [mre] might help us define a better solution or at least understand why certain solutions don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that you should be using `T &` not `T_ref`, or if you need it to be a regular type, `std::reference_wrapper<T>`.

If that isn't the case, write a `borrow_ptr` template, very similar to `unique_ptr` except that it also tracks if it doesn't own it's element. Then use `borrow_ptr<size_t> data;` in `T`, and discard `T_ref`.

As a sketch

```
template <typename T>
class borrow_ptr 
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> data;
    bool owns;
public:
    ~borrow_ptr() { if (!owns) data.release(); }
    // public surface of unique_ptr
};
```

Comment: a `shared_ptr` with a no-op deleter would be another option

Comment: `T &` does not work, as `class T` calls free() in its destructor. So, for instance, say a `T &` Obj goes out of scope it gets destroyed, then it tries to free arbitrary memory. It will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: `borrow_ptr` is an excellent idea. It would work, but is that the best we can do?

Comment: No, if a `T&` goes out of scope nothing happens. A reference is not an object, it's another name for an existing object

Comment: You haven't shown a reason why `HugeTpool` can't have `std::vector<T> _data;` instead of `size_t* _dataPool;`

Comment: Right !! The overhead of `vector<T>` is way too much. `T->pData` holds only little data, say 1 byte, but the `sizeof(T)` is `32`bytes. I typically have a large number of small Objects. `HugeTpool` coalesces the `T`s together, which helps eliminate the need to store all of `T`'s other data members. As an when required the Data members can be generated based on some global invariants.

Comment: Rather than putting those data members in `T`, can't the things that need them get them from `HugeTpool` instead?

Comment: No `T` is a predefined class, I can't modify it. That is why this workaround to emulate `T` like behaviour on top of the `HugeTpool` structure.